# How to get the current number of interactive user sessions in Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, language-agnostic, windows-services

I'm writing a Windows service that needs to know whether there are any users currently logged-on in the machine.

So far I've tried `Win32_LogonSession` (WMI), and `LsaEnumerateLogonSessions`/`LsaGetLogonSessionData` (secur32.dll).

Both work, and seem to return the same data, but they are too slow to update when a user log off:

- When the system starts, they return "0 interactive users". (OK)
- When I log on, they return "1 interactive user". (OK)
- But then when I log off, the number of users is kept at 1. After a new log-on, the number is 2, and so on.

Thus Win32_LogonSession nor LsaEnumerateLogonSessions are good enough. **The service needs to know within 5 minutes after the last interactive user leaves.**

Not even SysInternals' LogonSessions.exe gives up-to-date answers.
Also, the answer cannot be "monitor logon and logoff events and have a counter variable", because the service can be started at any time.

Comment: Are you sure the logon session is over?  The logon session will still exist if the token has been duplicated or if the user has been impersonated (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378338%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @Luke Well, I tested with straight logon+logoffs. No logon session token duplication or user impersonation are ocurring, as far as I know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ended up with the following approach: count the number of interactive sessions which have at least one process running.

### 1) Get the logon session id for each interactive session.

- LsaEnumerateLogonSessions (secur32.dll)
- LsaGetLogonSessionData (secur32.dll)
- [sessionData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380128.aspx).LogonType = [SECURITY_LOGON_TYPE.Interactive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380129.aspx) or sessionData.LogonType = SECURITY_LOGON_TYPE.RemoteInteractive
- **sessionData.LoginID**  *<- Keep this value in a LUID set.*
- LsaFreeReturnBuffer (secur32.dll)

### 2) Get the logon session id for each running process.

[First we need to enable the SeDebugPrivilege to the current application.]

- GetCurrentProcess (kernel32.dll)
- OpenProcessToken [TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374905.aspx) (advapi32.dll)
- LookupPrivilegeValue [SE_DEBUG_NAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb530716.aspx) (advapi32.dll)
- AdjustTokenPrivileges (advapi32.dll)
- CloseHandle (kernel32.dll)

[Then retrieve the data we want.]

- EnumProcesses (psapi.dll)
- OpenProcess [PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684880.aspx) (kernel32.dll)
- OpenProcessToken [TOKEN_QUERY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374905.aspx) (advapi32.dll)
- GetTokenInformation [TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS.TokenStatistics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379626.aspx) (advapi32.dll)
- **[accessTokenStatistics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379632.aspx).AuthenticationId**  *<- Keep this value in a LUID set.*
- CloseHandle (kernel32.dll)

### 3) Sets intersection cardinality

```
interactiveSessionsCount = | { sessionData.LoginID } ∩ { accessTokenStatistics.AuthenticationId } |
```

Obs: sessionData.LoginID and accessTokenStatistics.AuthenticationId are both of type [LUID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379261.aspx).

Comment: I know it's been answered some time ago, but I'm curious if you had a chance to update your algorithm. I just implemented it on my Windows 7 (and later Windows 8) OS and I'm getting about 7 or 8 interactive user sessions when in reality it's only one interactive user?

Comment: @tiago2014, thank you so much. You saved me HELLA hours trying to stumble through this. You're awesome.

Answer (score 1):

[WTSEnumerateSessionsA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsenumeratesessionsa) + [WTSQuerySessionInformationA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsquerysessioninformationa) work better with detecting active/interfactive sessions.